# How to access resources in dotnet core and fetch its URI

Tags: c#, .net-core, f#, uri, embedded-resource

In a class library of C# or F# I am trying to access certain files. I intend to pack the files together with the project, which makes them resources, as I understand. There is not many guides on docs right now addressing how resources work in .NET core.

In some tests of the .NET core library I see declarations of `EmbeddedResources` in project files. Are there other kinds of resources? And what are their pros and cons?

How to use the resource files through URI (specifically in this case I am expanding a entity reference for parsing XMLs). How should I create the correct URIs for resources. What is the relation between such URI, file paths, and relative file paths? How would they differ if I use them in applications other than .NET core libraries, say, a UWP app, and ASP.NET app, or a WPF app on .NET core.